# Visualize cardinality of multiple sets

Tags: matlab, plot

I have group of sets (which represents several clusters with their respective items) and each set contains different amount of items.

For example something like this (numbers inside are class IDs):

```
{1,2,3,4,5}
{6}
{7,8}
{9}
```

Which could of course be easily transformed into list of cardinalities `{5,1,2,1}`. What I need to do is to represent each cardinality visually.

The best way would probably be to display it by N randomly colored squares per set (like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aCluster-2.svg) - data set around `{20,10,10}`) but drawing four differently colored circles (with `radius = {5,1,2,1}`) would also be fine.

I also found [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) which provides similar output as the one need, but it doesn't provide any automatization for points localization.

I could generate random points and color them or generate those circles manually but I wander whether Matlab provides functionality for this.

**The idea is to show how group is separated into clusters...**

Comment: you can create the plot attached with matlab, but I admit I couldn't understand what it is you want to do. How does [5,1,2,1] relate to that plot you attached in the link?

Comment: @natan it's just an example for visualization, the data set is probably something like `{100,100,500}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [`pie`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pie.html) or [`pie3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pie3.html) plots?

```
card = cellfun( @numel, clusters ); % get the cardinality of each cluster
figure('Name','visualizing cluster cardinality');
subplot(121);
pie( card );
title('2D pie plot');
subplot(122);
pie3( card );
title('3D pie plot');
colormap( rand( numel(card), 3 ) ); % random color map
```

Comment: I actually like this idea, but the problem is that I have up to 108 different clusters (may be 4000 later) and it would be hardly readable (I guess) if it' would be gruped like that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [bar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) (or [barh](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/barh.html)):

```
bar([5 1 2 1])
```

radial options are [compass](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/compass.html), [polar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polar.html) and [rose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rose.html):

Comment: The problem is there may be many groups (up to 130), mentioned bars would be probably hard to read :-S

Comment: in that case why won't you just use `plot` ?